# Checkbox with codition ischecked all in android

Tags: android, checkbox

I have a `ListView` of `CheckBox`s. When I click the button if `isChecked`, all will success else failed.

Thanks all.

Answer (score 0):

```
SparseBooleanArray sba=new SparseBooleanArray(); // declare globally in adapter
convertview.onClickListener(new View.onClickListener(){
@Override
public void onClick()
{
 if(checkbox.isChecked())
 {
   sba.put(position,true);
 }
  else
 {
  sba.put(position,false);
 }

});
```

**At the end of Selection `checkedItems` ArrayList will hold your checked Items**

```
ArrayList<String> checkedItems=new ArrayList<String>();
ArrayList<String> initialItems=new ArrayList<String>();

  for(int position=0;position<sba.size();position++) 
  {
     if(sba.get(position))
     {
        checkedItems.Add(initialItems.get(position));
     }

   }
}
```